# All files in my new volume locked by sudden

Tags: drivers, permissions, volume-control

I am new in linux and i used dual boot. Few days ago i just realize that my new volume become locked and i can't do anything to all files and folder inside except read. Even though there is no problem before. I try to change all permission to read and write but still no effect.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6bcW.png)

Comment: If the "new volume" is a USB flash drive and if it happened suddenly then that's a warning the drive is about to fail. Backup ASAP.

Comment: Which file-system? windows one? By dualboot I always think fastboot.

Comment: thankyou for all your answers, but i have just solve it by updating my os